# How to build a python node as a component?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I have a python node that I would like to add to a composable node container.

I could not find any documentation on the python equivalent to the `rclcpp_components_register_node` cmake command. I would assume that I would need to adjust the python code of the node as well as the setup.py file.

Naively, I have just tried to add the executable in the `ComposableNode()`:

```
ComposableNode(
    package="foo",
    plugin="foo_node",
    name="foo",
),
```

but got the following error when launching:

```
[ERROR] [bar.container]: Could not find requested resource in ament index
[ERROR] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Failed to load node 'foo_node' of type 'foo_node' in container '/bar/container': Could not find requested resource in ament index
```

It would be great if you could help me figure this out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

> How to build a python node as a component?

As of ROS 2 Iron Irwinin [the features status](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/The-ROS2-Project/Features.html) mentions that the composition of node components at compile, link, load, or run time is currently only in C++.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I will try to keep an eye on this table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your node in launch.py file like this;

```
from launch import LaunchDescription

def generate_launch_description():
    # For example
    joy_node_command = Node(
        package='joy',
        executable='joy_node',
        name='joy'
    )
    
    ld = LaunchDescription()
    
    ld.add_action(joy_node_command)
    
    return ld
```

I hope this answer solves your problem. :)

Comment: Hi, I would like to launch it in a composition so it shares the process with related nodes, and I can use intraprocess communication. This does unfortunately not solve the issue.

Comment: @Metz oh okay, I got it. I think you have looked that link but you may have overlooked. https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/How-To-Guides/Launching-composable-nodes.html